# microsoft visual c++ compiler for python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am downloaded microsoft visual c++ compiler for python(2.7) now i upgrade python 2.7 to 3.6 and then i downloaded microsoft visual 14.0 redistributable.

Now i downloaded mod_wsgi using pip command..

C:\Windows\system32>set "MOD_WSGI_APACHE_ROOTDIR=C:/wamp64/bin/apache/apache2.4.23"

C:\Windows\system32>pip install mod_wsgi

This shows error..

error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools.

I am downloaded Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0(2017 build tools) http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools
Now i dont no how to integrate both of them..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to give the confident answer about this question.

In terms of my development environment, `pip` can find the VC++ path automatically, so I think it might be something difficult in this question.

However, when using Microsoft C++ Build Tools, you should use following command firstly:

`vcvarsall`

And then

`pip install mod_wsgi`

Answer (score 0):

If the required microsoft visual C++ build tools is already installed and still it is not working then update pip and check, I recently ran into this problem and after upgrading the pip issue is resolved.

command to upgrade the pip: python -m pip install --upgrade pip